# Circuit (Pseudo-Homeworks)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I'm studying Kirchoff's Laws and how to find $\Delta V$ between two points in a circuit (CC). I already know how to use it but I look on internet for more exercise to learn more and find this circuit

[image]

I'm a little confuse about it, because there is a wire in between that don't understand exactly. In this case I wanna find $\Delta V_{AB}=V_A-V_B$. I start to do this:

[image]

I write
$$\Delta V_{AB}=V_A-V_B = \Delta V_{AC} +\Delta V_{CD} +\Delta V_{DB} $$

Then if I apply Kirchhoff's voltage law in right part
$$ -30 + 6 I_3 + 4 I_3 =0$$
and I have the relations
$$ I_1 =2 A \quad \quad \Delta V_{AC}=5 I_1 \quad \quad \Delta V_{CD} =5-10 I_2  \quad \quad \Delta V_{DB}= 4 I_3 $$
But I'm not sure how to find $I_2$

Comment: So based on the answer given what is $V_{AB}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that the supplied current of the current source, **must** be equal to the current that flows through the 'back' of it, and therefore must be equal to the current that flows 'upward' from node $C$:

[image]

Then, applying KCL on node $C$:

[image]

Yields:
$$I_1 = I_1 +I_2$$

$$I_2=0A$$

Comment: How it is possible? I though that there should be non-zero current in all the wires...

Comment: Why would it not be possible? The current that the current source supplies is $I_1$, and the upper most current in this part o the diagram **has to be $I_1$**, and that tells us that $I_2$ must be $0$, according to Kirchhoff's Current Law.

Comment: How do you know that in A->C segment have to be I_1? Should not be $I_1=I_2+I_4$? (Where $I_4$ is another current that we don't know from C to A). Sorry, maybe I miss something in between

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to clear that confusion up, I hope this helps :)

Comment: great! Thank you very much :)